# Haskell: If-Block Evaluator works correctly within GHCI but not when its evaluated through a parsed expression

Tags: parsing, haskell, eval

I'm trying to write an evaluator for my language that takes a parsed if-block, evaluates all conditions and filters out the False branches and then picks one branch to take at random. I'm at the stage wherein I can filter out the branches and be left with my possible paths but only within GHCI. When I attempt to pass an if-block into my program through the command line, what occurs is if the first branch is True, that's the only branch that is taken, otherwise an empty list is returned regardless if there are any sub-branches or not. My evaluator for binary expressions works so I know that my error is with my logic in my if evaluator or parser.

Here is the behaviour through the command line:

```
~/Desktop/Olivia > ./Main "if (1 > 3)-> 1 + 1 [] (1 < 2)-> 2 + 2"
[] 
~/Desktop/Olivia > ./Main "if (1 < 3)-> 1 + 1 [] (1 < 2)-> 2 + 2"
[2]
```

Here is the behaviour through GHCI:

```
λ > b = SubIf (Expr (HInteger 2) Less (HInteger 1)) [(Expr (HInteger 45) Add (HInteger 45)), (Expr (HInteger 6) Add (HInteger 6))]
λ > c = SubIf (Expr (HInteger 2) Less (HInteger 3)) [(Expr (HInteger 5) Add (HInteger 5)), (Expr (HInteger 6) Add (HInteger 6))]
λ > a = If (Expr (HInteger 3) Less (HInteger 2)) [(Expr (HInteger 1) Add (HInteger 100)), (Expr (HInteger 2) Add (HInteger 2))] [b, c]
λ > eval b -- All False branches return a value of 1
1
λ > eval c
[10 12]
λ > eval a
[[10 12]]
```

This is my expected result. In the case of `n` number of sub if expressions, I will pick one list of the overall list as my branch to take before I go back to evaluate the loop guard and begin the next iteration of the program.

My data type:

```
data HVal
  = HInteger Integer
  | HBool    Bool
  | HString  String
  | HList    [HVal]
  | Expr    HVal Op HVal  
  | EqExpr  HVal Op HVal 
  | Neg      HVal
  | Assign   HVal   HVal  
  | Do       HVal   [HVal]
  | If       HVal   [HVal] [HVal]
  | SubIf    HVal  [HVal]
  | Load     String
  deriving (Eq, Read)
```

My Parsers:

```
parseIf :: Parser HVal
parseIf = do
 _  <-  string "if"
 spaces
 _  <-  string "("
 cond  <- (parseExpr <|> parseEqExpr <|> parseBool)
 _  <-  string ")->"
 expr  <- spaces *> many (parseExpression <* spaces)
 expr' <- spaces *> many (parseExpression <* spaces)
 return $ If cond expr expr'

parseSubIf :: Parser HVal
parseSubIf = do
  _ <- string "[]"
  spaces
  _ <- string "("
  cond <- (parseExpr <|> parseEqExpr <|> parseBool)
  _ <- string ")->"
  expr <- spaces *> many (parseExpression <* spaces)
  return $ SubIf cond expr
```

My Evaluator:

```
eval :: HVal -> HVal
---------- EVALUATING PRIMITIVES ----------
eval val@(HString _) = val
eval val@(HInteger _) = val
eval val@(HBool _) = val
eval val@(HList _) = val
eval (Expr x op y) = evalExpr x op y
eval (If cond expr expr') = evalIf cond expr expr'
eval (SubIf cond expr) = evalSubIf cond expr

evalIf :: HVal -> [HVal] -> [HVal] -> HVal
evalIf cond expr expr' = if ((eval cond) == (HBool True))
                            then HList $ map eval expr
                            else HList $ (filter (/= (HInteger 1)) (map eval expr'))

evalSubIf :: HVal -> [HVal] -> HVal
evalSubIf cond expr = if ((eval cond) == (HBool True))
                         then HList $ map eval expr
                         else (HInteger 1)
```

I think that the error may be with my parser for the if-block. My thinking behind it was that the if block contains the conditional for the first branch and what it evaluates to and then a list of sub expressions wherein each element of the list contains the branch conditional and what it evaluates to.

Comment: Sounds like you need to test the parser by itself, either in ghci or by printing the result of parsing in your compiled program.  You might need to derive `Show` for HVal so it can be printed.

Comment: `expr  <- spaces *> many (parseExpression <* spaces) ; expr' <- spaces *> many (parseExpression <* spaces)` is highly suspicious. I can't see what can be parsed by the second part `expr'` without getting captured by the first part `expr`. Why is `many` used there? Related: the constructor `If  HVal [HVal] [HVal]` uses lists, but I can't understand why.

Comment: @chi Many used such that one branch may contain many expressions if the conditional to it is true. That's why `If` takes lists. The first list refers to the possible expressions if the conditional of the first branch is true then the second list is the list containing the next `n` branches of If statements